# i have a question about binary search tree, this code:

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.right=self.left=None
        self.data = data
class Solution:
    def insert(self,root,data):
        if root==None:
            return Node(data)
        else:
            if data<=root.data:
                cur=self.insert(root.left,data)
                root.left=cur
            else:
                cur=self.insert(root.right,data)
                root.right=cur
        return root

    def getHeight(self,root):
        #Write your code here
        if not root:
            return -1
        else:
            return max(self.getHeight(root.right), self.getHeight(root.left)) + 1
T=int(input())
myTree=Solution()
root=None
for i in range(T):
    data=int(input())
    root=myTree.insert(root,data)
height=myTree.getHeight(root)
print(height)
```

I have 3 question:
1.How does getHeight() function works ?
2.why in getHeight() function:

```
if not root:
        return -1
```

why return -1, not 0

3.and in this code:

```
else:
            return max(self.getHeight(root.right), self.getHeight(root.left)) + 1
```

i think the max of result will + 1, but it's not true, it will * 1, i tried 2, it will * 2, i tried 3, it will * 3. Can you explain it ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question means?

Comment: i have just edit it, so can u explain it for me ?

Comment: The third question could still used better clarification. I did my best to answer it below, but I'm not sure if that's what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some parts of your question are not completely clear, but I think these answers address what you are asking.  I'm very open to edits to improve clarity:

1. `getHeight()` is a recursive function, so it calls itself as it
   proceeds along the tree.
   http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html
2. This sets it so when you get to the end of a branch it will select the max value from down the other branch, or if reaching both it won't add an uncalled for layer because (+1) + (-1) = 0.
3. The idea behind the last part of the code to keep doing something like: answer = 1 + go down the longest chain and do it again. So you've added +1 for ever level of the tree. And on the last one you'd get the result explained in part 2, giving you the correct result.

Example for part 3

```
      A
   B     C
  D E
```

1. When we check A, we return the max(left,right)+1. Which means we
   have to check B and C.
2. For C we return max(left,right)+1 and since there is nothing left or
   right below, it returns -1, and the score for C is -1+1=0.
3. For B, we return max(left,right)+1 so check D and E
4. For D and also for E we return max(left,right)+1 and since there is
   nothing left or right below of either, it returns -1, and the score
   for both D and E is -1+1=0. So lets start back up
5. Based on set 4 B = max(0,0)+1 = 1.
6. Back up to A, the only one not solved yet, we have A = max(1,0)+1 =
   2

So our score is 2

Comment: can u explain specifically how the code in part 3 works, i'm just beginner ?

Comment: I added a walk through of a simple example for part 3 that I hope explains that is going one

Comment: ok, i understood, i don't know what to say to thank you, thank you so much

Comment: If it helped, please accept the answer!